# Selenium shows java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Tags: eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have searched for the solution but I have not found the solution I always get this error

codigo :

```
public static void main(String [] args) {

          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\Ofima\\workspace\\OfimaWeb\\chromedriver.exe");  
          WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
          driver.get("http://ofimawebbeta.ofima.com/");
          driver.manage().window().maximize();
          driver.getTitle();
      }
```

Error :

```
Starting ChromeDriver (v2.9.248315) on port 41785
ene 19, 2018 9:48:49 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFORMACIÓN: Detected dialect: OSS
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
Build info: version: '3.8.0', revision: '924c4067df', time: '2017-11-30T11:37:19.049Z'
System info: host: 'PCPOF-021', ip: '10.72.4.128', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:92)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:325)
    at OfimaWeb.cartera.main(cartera.java:23)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

Comment: Which chrome version you are using ?

Comment: I am using this version Google Chrome is updated
Version 63.0.3239.132 (Official build) (64 bits)

Comment: So please use latest chrome driver  that may help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download ChromeDriver from

http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.33/

This ChromeDriver shall work with your version of Google Chrome.

Answer (score 3):

The error does gives us some hint as follows :

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

Which essentially implies that *ChromeDriver* binary is unable to spawn a new *Chrome Browser* process.

Your main issue is the **version compatibility** among the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *ChromeDriver v2.9* (released *2014-01-31*)
- Release Notes of [ChromeDriver v2.9_](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.9/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v31-34**

- You mentioned of using latest Chrome. I suppose it is *chrome=65.x*
- You are using *Selenium Version 3.8.0* (released *2017-11-30T11:37:19.049Z*) [as per the error stack trace within your question]

So there is a clear mismatch between requirement for *ChromeDriver v2.9* and the *Chrome Browser* version you are using. Hence *ChromeDriver* is unable to spawn the new `Chrome Browser` process.

---

### Solution

- Update *ChromeDriver* to current  *v2.35* level.
- Downgrade *Chrome* to  stable *Chrome v64.x* levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.35 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.9/notes.txt))
- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels *Version 3.8.1*.
- *Clean* and *Re-Build* your project through your *IDE*.
- Clear the *Browser Cache*
- Use [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores.
- If your *Web Browser* base version is too old, uninstall the *Web Browser* through [Revo Uninstaller](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) with *Moderate Scan* and install a recent *GA Released* version of the `Web Browser`.
- Execute your `@Test`.