# Selenium SocketTimeoutException after calling websites

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I use Selenium (standalone version) for testing websites. I used the ChromeDriver, but I tested it also with the FirefoxDriver.

My Problem: I get a java.net.SocketTimeoutException, by calling websites on first time, if they load very slow. It seems, that selenium dont want to wait, until the website built completely. If I run the application again, it works sometimes, because the website loads faster (caching maybe).

After searching on Google I found ways to set the timeouts, but it doesn't work:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

What can I do, that Selenium will wait for slower websites directly? I hope somebody can help me with this problem.

Comment: Increase your timeout values.

Comment: I've worked with Protractor.js and it uses selenium under the hood; I had to do what @RyanWilson said to do in my config.

Comment: selenium version?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium shows java.net.SocketException: Connection reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48343769/selenium-shows-java-net-socketexception-connection-reset)